# How to trigger the *start* of a Google Maps 'DrawingManager' drawing?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, eventtrigger

In my Google Maps based application, users often have to draw a pair of concentric circles on the map. I'm using the `google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager` for this. In the ideal scenario, a user draws the first circle normally, and then the process of drawing the second circle starts *automatically*, its center already set. So the user would only need one additional click to draw the second circle.

Here's what I tried:

```
var manager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    map: myMap,
    drawingControlOptions: {
        drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE]
    }
});

var phaseOne = true;

google.maps.event.addListener(manager, 'circlecomplete', function (circle) {
    if (phaseOne) {
        phaseOne = false;
        // already in drawing mode, so... just trigger a click event?
        google.maps.event.trigger(myMap, 'click', {
            stop: null,
            latLng: circle.getCenter()
        });
    } else {
        phaseOne = true;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Drawing single circles still works fine, and the `phaseOne` flag is being properly alternated. But the event trigger doesn't seem to do anything.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: No solution... but I Started messing around with the idea of adding a second circle that is editable. I think that miiight be able to get you close. Basically pop the circle where the mouse is, stop drawing mode, and then start resizing the new circle. I have no clue if this will work though. I did see on google's site though that the typical click events are disabled in drawing mode (at the bottom). [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawing#drawing_events]

Comment: I'm already automatically placing a second editable circle as the 'next best thing'. But simulating a click-event in non-drawing mode to resize it is pretty clever! I haven't tried that yet. :-) That being said, it feels like I should still be able to trigger an edit-mode click. If not through the Google Maps API, then through regular DOM events? But no success so far.

Comment: it would be useful to post whole example in jsfiddle

Answer (score 3):

I've finally got it work ! Like TravJenkins says, all the events are disabled while in drawing mode, I've try to play around with the Google API but can't find a way to do it. I seriously thinks that the Drawing Library can be greatly improved..

I've decided to emulate a click event, saving the coordinates of the previous click.

All I have to do is to affect two variables to detect while a circle is drawing and another to stop at the second to prevent infinite drawing.

Here is the code:

```
var draw = false
var already = false
var event

$('#map').click(function (e) {
  if (draw === true && already === false) {
    already = true;
    click(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    draw = false;
  } else if (draw === false) {
    event = e;
    already = false;
  }
  draw = false
})

function click (x, y) {
  var ev = document.createEvent('MouseEvent')
  var el = document.elementFromPoint(x, y)
  ev.initMouseEvent(
    'click', true, true, window, null, 0, 0,
    x, y,
    false, false, false, false, 0, null
  )
  el.dispatchEvent(ev)
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(manager, 'circlecomplete', function (circle) {
  draw = true
})
```

Comment: Looking good! :-) I'll have a closer look soon. Just a quick remark: the initial circle can also be drawn by mousedown-drag-mouseup, which you don't seem to capture yet. But, well, that's just a detail at this point.

Comment: Yeah, I've decided to do this because you only talk about click event in the post and the comment. Let me know ! :)

Comment: A problem with your code is that it uses native browser events rather than something like jQuery. I'm having trouble getting this jQueryized somehow... [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhelvens/36WcC/). What do you think?

Comment: I'm gonna see it, but is that a real problem to use javascript instead of jQuery for you ?

Comment: The reason why jQuery is preferable is that it is cross-browser compatible. Methods like `elementFromPoint` and `initMouseEvent` have subtle differences between browsers; sometimes not so subtle.

Comment: Yeah I understand, but I've already try to do this using jQuery, nothing seems to work at the moment, I think it's because of the Google Maps. Looking at the [W3C website](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20030331/ecma-script-binding.html) `initMouseEvent` is (or will be) standart, same for [`elementFromPoint`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t20), so for the moment you should use this, I'll try some things again anyway

Comment: I've update the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36WcC/3/) and the code to prevent `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. What do you think ?

Comment: Thanks. I had fixed the call-stack error myself by moving the artificial click event inbetween setting `already` and `draw`. And regarding jQuery: Unfortunately, something being a W3C standard doesn't mean that all browsers agree on how to interpret that standard. You will notice that the documents you're linking to are from 2003 and 2010, and still browsers vendors are divided in how, e.g., `initMouseEvent` should work.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I don't think there is a way to use `.trigger` event in jQuery and pass coordinates with the Google Maps, it's always triggered on the top left corner no matter what coordinates we give :(

Comment: I've noticed. It's weird, isn't it? Anyway, thanks for the effort! You can take the bounty, because you've come closest to a proper solution, I think. As it stands, though, I'd rather use a less than perfect solution that works on all browsers than a perfect one that works only on half. :-) Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I'll try to look around if a solution appear and tell you if I found something interesting. So are you gonna use your solution of create another circle that can be resize or mine for the moment ?

Comment: I'm now implementing my own drawing manager using the raw Google Maps API. This basically means setting up and breaking down the proper mouse-event listeners for each step, setting the right cursor, etc. --- I had hoped not to be forced to reinvent the wheel, but in the end this will give me much more flexibility, and I may just stick with it.

Comment: Okay hope your wheel is going to pan out :P

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully the google.maps team will add some methods to permit the developer draw some overlays from code or at least to attach new overlays to the `DrawingManager`, but currently is not the case.

I suggest you to use a different approach I demostrate in the following exemple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>    
    <title>Handling markers collection demo</title>

   <style type="text/css">
        html
        {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body
        {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #map-container
        {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            min-width:500px;
            min-height:300px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=drawing"></script>    

</head>


<body>
    <div id="map-container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var _map,
            manager;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            _map = new google.maps.Map($("#map-container")[0], mapOptions);

            manager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
                map: _map,
                drawingControlOptions: {
                    drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE]
                }
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(manager, 'circlecomplete', function (circle) {

                var center = circle.getCenter(), radius = circle.getRadius();

                manager.setDrawingMode(null);
                var circleOptions = {
                        center: center,
                        editable: true,
                        map: _map,
                        radius: radius * 0.80,
                        visible: true
                    },
                    newCircle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);

                google.maps.event.addListener(newCircle, 'center_changed', function () {
                    var oldCenter = center,
                        newCenter = newCircle.getCenter();

                    if (oldCenter.lat() != newCenter.lat() && oldCenter.lng() != newCenter.lng()) {
                        newCircle.setCenter(center);
                    }
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(newCircle, 'radius_changed', function () {
                    newCircle.setEditable(false);
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code is available and running in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5X83/)

Comment: Indeed. I was using something similar before, and I think I'll move back to it until there is a 'real' solution. Thanks!